# Why does my count() clause break my while statement?

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I am having an issue with a SQL call I have. Ultimately, I am running an AJAX call from a search box and returning the results to screen. I limit the results to 5 displayed but if the total number of results exceed 5, provide link to view all elsewhere. I thought by simply adding a `COUNT()` clause in this would take care of the issue and while `COUNT()` does return the full number of matches correctly, it kills my `while` statement when looping through and only returns the first result. When I remove `count()`, everything works.

## CODE

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['word']) && $_POST['word'] != "") 
    {
        $q=$_POST['word'];

            try {
                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB', 'USER', 'PW');
                $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $db->beginTransaction();

                $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(ID) as counter, ID, fname, lname FROM tablename WHERE fname LIKE ? or lname LIKE ? ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5");

                $stmt->execute(array('%'.$q.'%', '%'.$q.'%'));

                $foundrows = $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();

                $db->commit();
            }

            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                echo "There was a system DB error. <br>".$e->getMessage();          
            }               


        if(isset($foundrows) && $foundrows == 0) {
            echo "<div class='display_box' align='left'>
                No matching results found</div>";
        } else {        

                while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                    $counter = $row['counter'];

                    $id = $row['ID'];
                    $fname = $row['fname'];
                    $lname = $row['lname'];

            ?>
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000;">
                    <div class="display_box" align="left">

                    <?php echo $fname; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $lname; ?><br/>
                    </div></a>

<?php     
                }

                if(isset($counter) && $counter > 5) {
?>                  
                    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000;">
                    <div class="display_box" align="left">
                    <?php echo (5-$counter)." additional matches found."; ?>
                    </div></a>
<?php                                   
                }
        }
    }   
?>
```

Comment: Title should be a summary of your question

Comment: @meagar - I thought 'what da puh' was sufficient ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if the total number of results exceed
>   5, provide link to view all elsewhere

To determine the number of rows that would have been returned had there been no LIMIT clause, use [SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ID, fname, lname FROM tablename WHERE fname LIKE ? or lname LIKE ? ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5
```

Then, your call to `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` will return the number had there been no limit. Note: No other SQL calls should occur between the `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and the `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` statement or the value will not be correct.

Answer (score 2):

`COUNT()` is an aggregate operation on the table that returns just one row, which is why you're not getting 5 results as you expect from your query when including it.

One way you can get what you want is by using a `SUBSELECT` clause in your query:

`SELECT (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM tablename) as counter, ID, fname, lname FROM tablename WHERE fname LIKE ? or lname LIKE ? ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5`

This will return the 5 results you expect, with a full count of the rows in the table as a column in each row.

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with PDO or PHP. If you specify an aggregate function (like *COUNT()*, *MAX()*, ...) it needs to group the rows, because you can not count a single row (of course). If you do not specify *GROUP BY* it will collapse the whole result set.